# Are Construction of DOM and CSSOM parallel?

Tags: dom, html-rendering, cssom

In Critical Rendering Path, Is construction of DOM and CSSOM parallel? or Does construction of CSSOM process wait until construction of DOM will be ended? What is the sequence of Critical Rendering Path?

Thank you.